# Vulkan vkQueueSubmit: pWaitSemaphores is not a valid ponter

Tags: java, vulkan

I'm making a vulkan engine since a few days now and suddently I ran in a problem that breaks my head. This engine is written in java.
This is the code for the queue submission:

```
VkSubmitInfo.Buffer submitInfo = VkSubmitInfo.calloc(1, stack);
    submitInfo.sType$Default();
    submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount(1);
    submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores(VulkanContext.getImageAvailableSemaphores().get(VulkanContext.getCurrentFrame()).getBuffer());
    submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask(stack.ints(VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT));
    submitInfo.pSignalSemaphores(stack.longs(VulkanContext.getQueueCompleteSemaphores().get(VulkanContext.getCurrentFrame()).getHandle()));
    tCurrentFrame()).getBuffer());
    submitInfo.pCommandBuffers(stack.pointers(commandBuffer.getHandle()));

    VulkanContext.getInFlightFences().get(VulkanContext.getCurrentFrame()).reset();

    vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer.getHandle());
    int result = vkQueueSubmit(VulkanContext.getVulkanDevice().getGraphicsQueue(), submitInfo, VulkanContext.getInFlightFences().get(VulkanContext.getCurrentFrame()).getHandle().getHandle());
```

The error I receive from the validation layers is: **Invalid VkSemaphore Object 0x2847f9f8278. The Vulkan spec states: If waitSemaphoreCount is not 0, pWaitSemaphores must be a valid pointer to an array of waitSemaphoreCount valid VkSemaphore handles**

As you can see the semaphore exist but is not valid what ever thath means. I would realy appreciate it if some could explain to me what it means when the validation layers say that "the semaphore is not valid".

Comment: What does `getBuffer` do?

Comment: "As you can see the semaphore exist ". I don't see that. Demonstrate here that this is unambiguously true.

Comment: @krOoze The Validation Layers put out the pointervalue of the Semaphore. Just look in the post where the validatin layer message is.

Comment: @LolLol Does the value refer to properly created Semaphore that was not since destroyed?